# 500 error / Segmentation Fault - Magento

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

I am having an issue with a 500 error on a certain page:  `http://www.artevolution.com/shop/abstract.html?p=9`

This was the support ticket i got in return:

It looks like the segmentation fault is occurring on the following query:

```
SELECT `_default_table`.`entity_id`,
       `_default_table`.`entity_type`,
       Ifnull(_store_table.code_id, _default_table.code_id)
       AS `code_id`,
       Ifnull(_store_table.store_id, _default_table.store_id)
       AS `store_id`,
       Ifnull(_store_table.control_script, _default_table.control_script)
       AS
       `control_script`,
       Ifnull(_store_table.tracking_script, _default_table.tracking_script)
       AS
       `tracking_script`,
       Ifnull(_store_table.conversion_script, _default_table.conversion_script)
       AS
       `conversion_script`,
       Ifnull(_store_table.conversion_page, _default_table.conversion_page)
       AS
       `conversion_page`,
       Ifnull(_store_table.additional_data, _default_table.additional_data)
       AS
       `additional_data`
FROM   `googleoptimizer_code` AS `_default_table`
       LEFT JOIN `googleoptimizer_code` AS `_store_table`
              ON _store_table.entity_id = _default_table.entity_id
                 AND _store_table.entity_type = _default_table.entity_type
                 AND _store_table.store_id = 2
WHERE  ( _default_table.entity_id = '' )
       AND ( _default_table.entity_type = 'category' )
       AND ( _default_table.store_id IN ( 0, '2' ) )
ORDER  BY `_default_table`.`store_id` DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

You'll want to have a developer take a look into what is generating this query, as well as the other three queries that I mentioned (I'll provide them again below for your convenience) to see if the they can pinpoint what is occurring in the code (that might be causing a query loop). The queries are as follows:

```
SELECT `catalog_category_entity`.*
FROM   `catalog_category_entity`
WHERE  ( entity_id = '' );
```

```
SELECT `attr_table`.*
FROM   `catalog_category_entity_varchar` AS `attr_table`
WHERE  ( attr_table.entity_id = '' )
       AND ( attr_table.store_id IN ( 0, '2' ) )
UNION
SELECT `attr_table`.*
FROM   `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `attr_table`
WHERE  ( attr_table.entity_id = '' )
       AND ( attr_table.store_id IN ( 0, '2' ) )
UNION
SELECT `attr_table`.*
FROM   `catalog_category_entity_text` AS `attr_table`
WHERE  ( attr_table.entity_id = '' )
       AND ( attr_table.store_id IN ( 0, '2' ) )
UNION
SELECT `attr_table`.*
FROM   `catalog_category_entity_datetime` AS `attr_table`
WHERE  ( attr_table.entity_id = '' )
       AND ( attr_table.store_id IN ( 0, '2' ) )
ORDER  BY `store_id` ASC;
```

```
SELECT `_default_table`.`entity_id`,
       `_default_table`.`entity_type`,
       Ifnull(_store_table.code_id, _default_table.code_id)
       AS `code_id`,
       Ifnull(_store_table.store_id, _default_table.store_id)
       AS `store_id`,
       Ifnull(_store_table.control_script, _default_table.control_script)
       AS
       `control_script`,
       Ifnull(_store_table.tracking_script, _default_table.tracking_script)
       AS
       `tracking_script`,
       Ifnull(_store_table.conversion_script, _default_table.conversion_script)
       AS
       `conversion_script`,
       Ifnull(_store_table.conversion_page, _default_table.conversion_page)
       AS
       `conversion_page`,
       Ifnull(_store_table.additional_data, _default_table.additional_data)
       AS
       `additional_data`
FROM   `googleoptimizer_code` AS `_default_table`
       LEFT JOIN `googleoptimizer_code` AS `_store_table`
              ON _store_table.entity_id = _default_table.entity_id
                 AND _store_table.entity_type = _default_table.entity_type
                 AND _store_table.store_id = 2
WHERE  ( _default_table.entity_id = '' )
       AND ( _default_table.entity_type = 'category' )
       AND ( _default_table.store_id IN ( 0, '2' ) )
ORDER  BY `_default_table`.`store_id` DESC
LIMIT  1;
```

I've also placed a copy of the strace, and the associated queries from the strace, in the following location on the server: 
http://deathbecomesher.ca/artevo/segFaultPageLoadQueries.txt
http://deathbecomesher.ca/artevo/segFaultPageLoadStrace.txt

Does anyone have an ideas on how to fix this? Im a new developer and unsure of how to proceed. Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: More information is needed. What is that page - is it a product view page, category page, etc? Did you provide just a part of support ticket (there is "...as well as the other three queries that I mentioned..." - but the queries were not mentioned anywhere before in your StackOverflow question) - so you'd better provide whole support response, not just a part of it. And you'd need to provide http-links to the text documents, not some internal path on a server, because nobody can log in and fetch those docs by internal paths.

Comment: That is the entire ticket, the three queries are after 'The queries are as follows:' It is a category page.

Comment: What about segfault trace logs - where did they disappear from the question?

Comment: I re added it, having troubles with server being full so added it to a different one:http://deathbecomesher.ca/artevo/segFaultPageLoadQueries.txt http://deathbecomesher.ca/artevo/segFaultPageLoadStrace.txt

Comment: You're unlikely to find an answer here — the query in question uses a table named `googleoptimizer_code`.  That table doesn't ship as part of standard CE Magento, and I'm guessing it's something custom you had done to your site (or was done pre involvement of your site). You actually need to hire a developer to look at your specific system and debug the problems.